# useEffect getting called twice in react v18

Tags: javascript, reactjs, console, frontend, use-effect

I created an all-new react app to test this myself because one of my friend was facing this issue.
App.js code ->

```
function App() {

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('on init gets called');
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      Hello my first react app      
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

There is no other component present in the app. Following is the index.js code ->

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

console.log present in useEffect gets printed twice when we load the application for the first time.
I want it to be printed only once.

Comment: That's what's _supposed_ to happen: https://reactjs.org/blog/2022/03/29/react-v18.html#new-strict-mode-behaviors

Comment: for me , it's run only once. maybe something else trigger another rendering...

https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-shamir-s8tj7z?file=/src/App.js

Comment: for me also this happening exactly but by removing react strict mode in index.js issue cleared
but why this happening in this project last created project not react like this

@jonrsharpe thanks for for sharing

Comment: It's because of React.StrictMode

Comment: You need to do this way:     const isMounted = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isMounted.current) return;
    isMounted.current = true;


    // ...rest of your code goes here...
  },[])

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72238175/react-18-useeffect-is-getting-called-two-times-on-mount

Answer (score 2):

A tweak that worked for me ->
Removed strict mode of react and it works normally. Not sure if there can be other solutions to this or why it was happening.

Comment: const isMounted = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isMounted.current) return;
    isMounted.current = true;


    // ...rest of your code goes here...
  },[])

Comment: Removing StrictMode is the last thing to do. For a more detailed answer, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72238175/why-useeffect-running-twice-and-how-to-handle-it-well-in-react